# How to perform equivalent of JSTL's c:url in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

I have some JavaScript that is making an Ajax call to a relative url (using jQuery).

```
var servletUrl = "someservlet";

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: servletUrl,
    success: function(response) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Where `"someservlet"` is:

```
@WebServlet("/someservlet")
public class SomeServlet extends HttpServlet
```

I use this same script in multiple pages. When used from a page that is in the servlet context root, then the relative url resolves relative to the servlet context root, which is correct. When used from a page that is in a subfolder the URL resolves relative to the subfolder, which will return 404 error.

I would like to be able to reuse this JavaScript without having to modify it depending on the type of page that it is used within. Ideally, I need the equivalent of the JSTL's `<c:url>` tag. Is there anything in JavaScript that allows me to create URLs relative to the servlet context root?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Several options:

1. Set a HTML `<base>` element with that value (note: has its own [advantages and disadvantages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889076/is-it-recommended-to-use-the-base-html-tag))

   ```html
   <head>
       <base href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/" />
       ...
   </head>
   ```

   and then in JS:

   ```
   var contextPath = $("base").attr("href");
   var servletUrl = contextPath + "someservlet";
   // ...
   ```

   ---
2. *Or* set a data attribute somewhere

   ```html
   <html data-contextPath="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/">
       ...
   </html>
   ```

   and then in JS:

   ```
   var contextPath = $("html").data("contextPath");
   var servletUrl = contextPath + "someservlet";
   // ...
   ```

   ---
3. *Or* set a global JS variable with that value (poor practice):

   ```html
   <head>
       ...
       <script>var contextPath = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/";</script>
   </head>
   ```

   and then in JS:

   ```
   var servletUrl = contextPath + "someservlet";
   // ...
   ```

Comment: I tried your second option and it worked, with a little tweak. I had to modify the second substring parameter from 1 to 0 because it was giving me a URL with two slashes after the port number. That led to a 404 error. But with that little fix it worked great. Thanks very much.